# ReferenceError: NumberDecimal is not defined in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I tried to use

`db.orders.insert({"Price":NumberDecimal("12.34")})`

it throws this error

`"ReferenceError: NumberDecimal is not defined"` in Node.js

But it works fine in robo3T

`db.getCollection('orders').insert({"Price":NumberDecimal("12.34")})`

MongoDB shell version: v3.4.7

MongoDB server version:3.4.7

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us the context where you are using the code? Try inserting without the `NumberDecimal()` wrapper i.e.`db.orders.insert({"Price": 12.34}, (err, result) => console.log(result));`

Comment: Please verify the shell version once again, this should work starting from shell version 3.4

Comment: This works fine - db.orders.insert({"Price": 12.34}, (err, result) => console.log(result));

Comment: But my question is why NumberDecimal() throwing error

Comment: I double checked -MongoDB shell version: v3.4.7

MongoDB server version:3.4.7

Answer (score 3):

Replace `NumberDecimal("12.34")` with `mongodb.Decimal128.fromString('12.34')`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18740128)

Comment: why doesnt it provide an answer to the question? Decimal128 should be the nodejs mongodb native equivalent to NumberDecimal

Answer (score 1):

You no need to Write NumberDecimal in NodeJS
as you write

```
db.orders.insert({"Price":NumberDecimal("12.34")})
```

you can write the above query as

```
var price= parseFloat("12.34");
db.orders.insert({"Price" : price})
```

in case you are using mongoose schema, you can define the data type of your structure and mongo will automatically take the related datatypes as u have already defined in mongoose schema during the time of insert

Comment: when i try `parseFloat`, it inserts as a `Double`.  MongoDB shell version v4.0.3.